# Is there a vertical equivalent of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule?

Tags: tables, formatting, vertical, horizontal

I have this table, but I think it would look better if it rotated 90º and became horizontal, to save vertical space and for better reading. I would like to tranpose the table while maintaining the style of the `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` lines being thicker than the `\midrule`, but I don't know how to do so with vertical lines. Is it even possible?

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Number of units} & Mesh size & Number of elements \\
\midrule
1                                   & 59            & 5308 \\
2                                   & 88            & 5208 \\
3                                   & 90            & 3741 \\
4                                   & 100           & 3920 \\
5                                   & 112           & 3940 \\
6                                   & 128           & 3537 \\
7                                   & 134           & 3794 \\
8                                   & 150           & 3824 \\
9                                   & 160           & 3710 \\
10                                  & 172           & 3339 \\
15                                  & 214           & 1720 \\
20                                  & 264           & 938 \\
25                                  & 272           & 878 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption[Relationship between mesh properties with the number of units]{Relationship between mesh properties with the number of units}
\label{tab:maxsizeandnumberofunits}
\end{table}
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to keep the `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` commands and also add vertical lines to your table. Please be aware that the horizontal lines from the booktabs package werde desirned to be used without vertical lines at all and are thus not compatible with vertical lines. If I did not understand you correctly, please add a sketch of the desired output to your question.

Comment: Essentially, I would like the table to flip 90º and the line thickness remain the same, meaning that the \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule would become vertical.

Comment: Like that? https://i.stack.imgur.com/No1Fk.png Or do you also want to transpose the contents of the table (14 columns and 4 rows instead of 4 columns and 14 rows)?

Comment: The second one, with the vertical lines of the first!

Comment: 14 columns won't fit into the textwidth of a regular `article` class.

Comment: Maybe I should preserve this table the way it is, but for tables with fewer columns, how could I do it?

Comment: Since booktabs discourages vertical lines, the short answer is no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `tabular` environment currently contains 1 header row and 13 data rows. If you were to transpose this table, it would have 14 [!] columns in total. Unless you're also willing to either rotate each cell's content by 90 degrees or to choose a very very small font size (and, either way, making the table well-nigh unreadable), there's little chance that a 14-column table will fit inside the width of the text block.

I suggest that you instead spruce up the appeal of the table a bit by (i) introducing line breaks in the header cells, (ii) aligning all numbers on their respective (implicit) decimal markers with the help of the `siunitx` package, (iii) providing a bit of extra whitespace after every third row or so, and (iv) arranging for some additional visual cohesion between the tablar material and the caption by embedding both in a `threeparttable` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{skip=0.5\baselineskip,justification=raggedright}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{threeparttable}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} T{2.0}T{3.0}T{4.0} @{}}
\toprule
{Number of}  & {Mesh size} & {Number of}\\
{units}      &             & {elements} \\
\midrule
 1    &  59  & 5308 \\
 2    &  88  & 5208 \\
 3    &  90  & 3741 \\ \addlinespace
 4    & 100  & 3920 \\
 5    & 112  & 3940 \\ 
 6    & 128  & 3537 \\ \addlinespace
 7    & 134  & 3794 \\
 8    & 150  & 3824 \\
 9    & 160  & 3710 \\ \addlinespace
10    & 172  & 3339 \\ 
15    & 214  & 1720 \\
20    & 264  &  938 \\ 
25    & 272  &  878 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Relationship between mesh properties and number of units}
\label{tab:maxsizeandnumberofunits}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the  `boldline`  package, from the `shipunov` bundle, which defines a `V{some number}` column type, which replaces the standard column separator; the number is the factor by which the default rule thickness (0.4pt) is multiplied. The samde package also defines variable thickness horizontal rule, with syntax `\hlineB{some number}` and `\clineB{cols}{some number}`, without the bertical padding of the booktabs rules, so that vertical and horizontal bold lines do intersect.

As there would be  many columns,  you can make such a table fit the line width, playing with the value of `\tabcolsep`, the font size, and have more sensible margins  loading `geometry`.

Her is my trial:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{boldline} 

\begin{document}

begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\small\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}V{2.5}lV{1.6}*{13}{c}V{2.5}@{}}
\hlineB{2.5}
\makecell[l]{Number of\\ units} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 15 & 20 &25 \\[0.5ex]
\hlineB{1.6}
Mesh size & 59 & 88 & 90 & 100 & 112 & 128 & 134 & 150 & 160 & 172 & 214 & 264 & 272\\[0.5ex]
\makecell[l]{ Number of\\ elements} & 5308 & 5208 & 3741 & 3920 & 3940 & 3537 & 3794 & 3824 & 3710 & 3339 & 1720 & 938 & 878\\
\hlineB{2.5}
  \end{tabular}
 \caption[Relationship between mesh propert& 3710 \\ ies with the number of units]{Relationship between mesh properties with the number of units} \label{tab:maxsizeandnumberofunits}
 \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]